# Using charAt in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my assignment:

> Write a program where the user enters a string, and the program echoes it to the monitor with one character per line:

```
C:\>java LinePerChar
Enter a string:
Octopus

O
c
t
o
p
u
s
```

I have tried, but I'm getting some compilation errors. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class CharactorEcho{
    public static void main(String args []){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string :");

        try {
            String inputString = sc.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i < sc.length(); i++) {
                char c = inputString.charAt(i);
                System.out.println("" + c);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code seems fine. What's the problem?

Comment: can you share your compilation errors with us?

Comment: ALso note println prints it on its own line, o c t...all going to be on different lines.  Try just "print", then do a "println()" with nothing in it after the loop exits

Comment: he's looping over the scanner -.-

Comment: Error : CharactorEcho.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method length()
location: class java.util.Scanner
                                for(int i=0; i<sc.length(); i++){
                                                 ^
CharactorEcho.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IOException
location: class CharactorEcho
                        }catch(IOException e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two Issues:**

Change `for(int i=0; i<sc.length(); i++){` to `for(int i=0; i<inputString.length(); i++){`

You care comparing against the scanner and not the input string.

**Also, please try catching**

```
   java.util.NoSuchElementException
   java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

in place of `IOException`, as your statement `sc.nextLine()` with throws `NoSuchElementException` and `IllegalStateException`, not `IOException`.

Make sure you add the related import statements.

Answer (score 7):

In your loop, you should be looping over the length of the `String` that you get from the `Scanner.nextLine`, not the scanner itself.

```
for(int i=0; i<inputString.length(); i++){
```

If you want the input to be echoed with each character on the *same* line, use `System.out.print` instead of `println`.

Comment: `length` **is not** a field of `String`, it actually is a method.

Comment: Still this error is there

CharactorEcho.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IOException
location: class CharactorEcho
                        }catch(IOException e)

Comment: @ŦhųLẩnåFệrñảnDö: be sure to add `import System.io.IOException;` in your import section: you need to import the classes that you're using

Comment: @pb2q - import java.io.*; added..but still this error comes " CharactorEcho.java:19: exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of
corresponding try statement
                        }catch(IOException e)
                         ^

Comment: @ŦhųLẩnåFệrñảnDö You shouldn't be surrounding that code in a try-catch statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `IOException`. Add this line to the top of your code, just after the `package` line if you have one:

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

Also, you're asking `sc` for a length instead of the string, so change your `for` to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
```

Really though, you shouldn't be catching `IOException`. In fact, your code will never throw an exception. This is really all you need:

```
public static void main(String args []){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string :");

    String inputString = sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i < sc.length(); i++) {
        char c = inputString.charAt(i);
        System.out.println("" + c);
    }
}
```

Calling `nextLine` on a `Scanner` made with `System.in` will only throw an exception if `System.in` isn't accessible, and it won't even be an `IOException`, so don't worry about it.

One final observation, you don't need to do `"" + c` in your `println`. `System.out` has a `println` method specifically for `char`, so you can just call:

```
System.out.println(c);
```